# C++ Template specialization for subclasses with abstract base class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, enable-if

Let's say I have a pure abstract base class. A class template implements this interface, and is specialized. Now, my issue is that this specialization should be able to handle subclasses of the specialization. So, I tried enable_if, but then the subclass ends up being abstract... How can I get around this?

By example:

```
// This example doesn't work because a subclass of A does not satisfy the
// specialization for B<T>::foo()
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class B : public A {
    ...
public:
    ...
    void foo();
    ...
};

void B::foo() {
    ...
}

template <>
void B<A>::foo() {
    ...
}

class C : A {
    ...
public:
    ...
    void foo();
    ...
};

int main() {
    B<C> bar;  // I was like "this is gonna work!! :) :D"
    bar.foo(); // But this calls B::foo() instead of B<A>::foo()... :'( *sob*
}
```

And another example:

```
// This example doesn't work because B ends up being abstract
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class B : public A {
    ...
public:
    ...
    template <class U=T>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<U, A>::value, void>::type
    foo() {
        ...
    }

    template <class U=T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<U, A>::value, void>::type
    foo() {
        ...
    }
};

class C : A {
    ...
public:
    ...
    void foo();
    ...
};

int main() {
              // I got excited thinking this would work \(^.^)/
    B<C> bar; // and then it didn't because B is abstract /(-_-)\ ...
    bar.foo();
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks!!

Comment: Try `virtual void foo() = 0`

Comment: @Ylisar Sorry, that was a typo on the part of the example. Of course, if it was not virtual I would have other issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`B<C>` and `B<A>` are distinct types, so your first case will never work.

What you want to do is to specialize the template for all classes `T` for which `std::is_base_of<A, T>::value` is `true`. For that, use a default template parameter with partial specialization:

```
template <class T, bool = std::is_base_of<A, T>::value>
class B : public A {
public:
    void foo() override { std::cout << "A is not base of T!" << std::endl; }
};


template <class T>
class B<T, true> : public A {
public:
    void foo() override { std::cout << "A is base of T!" << std::endl; }
};
```

When A is a base of T, the `bool` parameter is `true` so the partial specialization is used. Otherwise, the base template is used.

Note that `is_base_of` will return `true` even if `A` is an inaccessible base of `T`, so you may also want to add a `is_convertible<T*, A*>` check.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7287c871bcf83af4).

Comment: Perhaps this would be better off split into a different question, but let's say there is also a specialization for std::vector<U>. But I also want a specialization for when U is a subclass of A... I tried it by adding another parameter which for the default case is bool = false and then having a bool = std::is_base_of<A, U>::value again, but I couldn't get it to work... I have an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e68f8ba1c81a022e) here. Any ideas? Also, where can I read about the type of partial specialization you use? I couldn't find anything... Thanks!

Comment: @kotakotakota Should probably be a separate question.

Comment: Actually, [just got it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ee8e8c99d786c1e). Thanks :)

Comment: @kotakotakota I'd probably specialize the `vector` variety with two parameters to take into account custom allocators, but otherwise nicely done :)

Comment: Ohh, good idea.

Someone opened my eyes to [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85795ee96cc773e8) solution which I think is really nice for this case as well.